# OpenShift Pyramid logging to file

Tags: python, logging, openshift, pyramid

I'm deploying my Pyramid app to OpenShift. I'm having a hard time with the logging configuration. I must log to a file so I have this:

```
[loggers]
keys = root, myapp, sqlalchemy

[handlers]
keys = console, filelog

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_myapp]
level = INFO
handlers = filelog
qualname = myapp
propagate = 0

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[handler_filelog]
class = FileHandler
args = ('%(here)s/myapp.log', 'a')
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

The `myapp.log` file was created, however when I push my changes no logging is found on this file. And, another thing puzzling me, is that my code logs some warnings that are shown in the `python.log` visible through `rhc tail`, but my desired file has no content.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you starting your Pyramid application? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058215/why-is-my-log-level-not-being-used-when-using-loadapp-from-paste-deploy for how things work on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the filelog handler to the root logger.

```
[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console, filelog
```

Comment: Nope, file is still empty